# How to import a static library on an Android project?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I'm currently trying to import a very simple C++ static library in an Android project.

Here is what the static library project looks like:

[image: Static library project]

I managed to generate the library and locate the `.a` files for each configuration (`arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86`, `x86_64`).

Now I'm trying to import it on an Android project, and here is what I did:

- in `src/main/cpp/jucedemo/lib` , I added the 4 directories (`arm64-v8a` , `armeabi-v7a` , `x86` , `x86_64`), with the different versions of my `libJuceDemo.a` in each directory
- I also added a `include` directory with `JuceTest.h` in it, as you can see here:
  [image: C++ static library in Android project]
- I added the following in my `CMakeLists.txt` file:
  [image: CMakeLists.txt content]

Then I tried to call the code of the library from my JNI (C++) code of my Android app:

- In another C++ file of my Android project (`native-lib.cpp`), I import the `JuceTest.h` header like this:

```
#include "jucedemo/lib/include/JuceTest.h
```

- In that same file (`native-lib.cpp`), in a function, I try to use the `JuceTest` class:

```
jucetest::JuceTest juceTest;
juceTest.getTexte();
```

Now when I try to compile and run my Android app, I get these errors:

```
error: undefined reference to 'jucetest::JuceTest::JuceTest()'
error: undefined reference to 'jucetest::JuceTest::getTexte()'
error: undefined reference to 'jucetest::JuceTest::~JuceTest()'
```

I believe there is something wrong with the content of the `JuceTest.h` header file in the `include` directory, but I can't find what it is.

Also, here is the [CMakeLists.txt](http://s519716619.onlinehome.fr/exchange/juce/CMakeLists.txt) used to compile the library.

What should I change so I can call my library code from the JNI code of my Android app?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Plase post the CMakeLists.txt where you build the library that links against `JuceDemo`.

Comment: @Michael I updated my post. It's a long and auto-generated `CMakeLists.txt`, so this is why I put a link.

Comment: I don't see native-lib.cpp mentioned anywhere in that file.

Comment: native-lib.cpp is in the parent project, but it could be any C++ file, actually.

Comment: The makefile I was asking for is the one where you build native-lib.

Comment: That's the one I mentioned in my post, just under "I added the following in my CMakeLists.txt file". Or maybe you need the whole file?

Comment: Yes, you should show how you are trying to build the library that fails to link. And post it in text form, not as a screenshot.

Comment: OK, here it is: http://s519716619.onlinehome.fr/exchange/juce/CMakeLists2.txt

Comment: OK so adding `${JuceDemo_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libJuceDemo.a` in `target_link_libraries()` solved my problem.